# Flutter misunderstanding - refresh and stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I'm stuck and I think I'm completely lost in Flutter's logic. I want to do the following :

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
   
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              ** I WANT TO CALL REFRESH ON THE EVENT LIST**
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          EventList(),
...

class EventList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EventListState createState() => _EventListState();
}

class _EventListState extends State<EventList> {
  List<Event> eventList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEventList();
  }

  Future<Null> getEventList() async {
   
    // Fill eventList from a web service ...

    setState(() {
  
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
         child: (eventList == null || eventList.length == 0)
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (eventList == null) ? 0 : eventList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
...
```

This logic works to make the first fetch of data using GET on a web service.

How can I call a refresh() to get new data on the HomeScreen and ask EventList to refresh (call getEventList() again) and rebuild ?

Thank you

Comment: use streambuilder for it

Comment: Thanks. How can I pass the refresh call from a user clicking on Icons.refresh to the EventList's streambuilder ?

Comment: Was there a reason that you created 2 stateful widgets?

Comment: Hello P4yam; whether I use a stateless or a stateful widget, I cannot see how I can pass a refresh event from a button on my screen to the EventList or delete the current EventList/create a new one upon clicking on refresh. PS: the EventList is used on different screens and that's why I wanted to separate the screen from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Working demo simulate 3 seconds network delay and show random number 
Step 1: call `setState` in `IconButton`'s `onPressed`

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

Step 2 : In `didUpdateWidget` of `_EventListState` use `addPostFrameCallback` to call `getEventList()`

```
@override
  void didUpdateWidget(EventList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getEventList();
    });
  }
```

working demo

[image]

Execution sequence when click refresh button

```
didUpdateWidget
build
getEventList
build for clear EventList
build for add EventList
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class Event {
  String title;

  Event({this.title});
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          EventList(),
        ]));
  }
}

class EventList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EventListState createState() => _EventListState();
}

class _EventListState extends State<EventList> {
  List<Event> eventList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEventList();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(EventList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getEventList();
    });
  }

  Future<Null> getEventList() async {
    Random random = new Random();

    setState(() {
      eventList.clear();
    });

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});

    List<Event> newEventList = List<Event>.generate(
        3, (index) => Event(title: random.nextInt(100).toString()));

    setState(() {
      eventList.addAll(newEventList);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
            child: (eventList == null || eventList.length == 0)
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: (eventList == null) ? 0 : eventList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(title: Text(eventList[index].title));
                    })));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to create such a detailed and accurate demo. I had no knowledge of the didUpdateWidget call. Now I know and that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One question though. How did you make the animated GIF ? So cool.

Comment: @AlainZelink, you can use https://www.screentogif.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your issue.

1. The first one would be to call setState in your MainState class after fetching the data. This will cause all children widgets to rebuild. But to do so you will also need to save the data inside your MainState class and pass it to your EventList widget as an argument. (Note that your EventList widget does not need to be Stateful anymore! Since it should not call the setState method any longer).
2. The second option, if you really want your function to be inside your EventListState class, is to create a controller that you instantiate in your MainState class. But that is quite a lot of work for a task as simple as this one.
3. The third one is to create a Service which would be a separated class exposing a Stream on which you will push your data whenever it is needed. I know this may sound complicated so for this one here is a theoretical example:

   ```
   class MyEventService {
     final StreamController<List<Event>> stateStreamController = StreamController<List<Event>>.broadcast();

     Stream<ActionState> get stateStream => stateStreamController.stream;

     Future<void> refresh() { fetchFromServer... then stateStreamController.push(data);
   }
   class MainState {
      build(..) => Scaffold(... Button(onPushed: myEventServiceInstance.refresh)
    }

   class EventList {
      build(..) => StreamBuilder(stream: myEventServiceInstance.stream...)

   }
   ```

I hope this helped you, do not hesitate to ask if you want a more complex sample!

Comment: Thank you Gaspard. chunhunghan's (above) solution seems perfect for my problem. But I will remember the StreamController solution for other complex problems.

Answer (score 0):

in flutter you cant call a child function from a parent what I would recommend is combining them in a single stateful widget or put the scaffold in the eventList widget so the appbar and the ListView are in the same statfull Widget

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'home_screen';

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Event> eventList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getEventList();
  }

    Future<Null> getEventList() async {
   
    // Fill eventList from a web service ...

    setState(() {
  
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
   
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () => getEventList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildEventList(),
        ]
      ),);

  }




  Widget buildEventList()(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
         child: (eventList == null || eventList.length == 0)
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: (eventList == null) ? 0 : eventList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
..
                }),
    }

  }
```